# Why does this produce an assertionerror even though it's exactly what was taught?

Tags: python

I'm completing something for Coursera, and this is the code I made:

```
def getFactors(x):
    """Returns a list of factors of the given number x.
    Basically, finds the numbers between 1 and the given integer that divide the number evenly.

    For example:
    - If we call getFactors(2), we'll get [1, 2] in return
    - If we call getFactors(12), we'll get [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12] in return
    """
    
    factors=[]
        
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        if x%1==0:
            factors.append(i)
        print(factors)
```

Yet,

```
num = 2
factors_test = [1, 2]
factors = getFactors(num)
assert_equal(factors_test, factors, str(factors) + ' are not the factors of ' + str(num))

num = 12
factors_test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
factors = getFactors(num)
assert_equal(factors_test, factors, str(factors) + ' are not the factors of ' + str(num))

num = 13
factors_test = [1, 13]
factors = getFactors(num)
assert_equal(factors_test, factors, str(factors) + ' are not the factors of ' + str(num))

# test existence of docstring
assert_true(len(getFactors.__doc__) > 1, "there is no docstring for getFactors")
print("Success!")
```

I get an assertionerror:

AssertionError: [1, 2] != None : None are not the factors of 2

Comment: You're not returning the ```factors``` variable in ```getFactors```

Comment: You're just printing the factors, not returning them from your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, you don't have a return value from the getFactors() function. Add this line to the end:

```
return factors
```

Once you do that, you'll maybe notice another bug. You are testing for the number modulus 1 == 0, which isn't quite right. You probably meant to be testing for modulus i. You'd have to replace this line:

```
if x%1==0:
```

with this line:

```
if x%i==0:
```

It's hard to see, but the first one uses the digit 1, and the second the letter i.